# How to fix indentation for *.nix files?

Tags: neovim, indentation, filetype-nix

How can I tell Neovim not to ignore characters after `//` as well as treat   (space) in lists as separator when it comes to indentation?

- Closing `};` below `users.root` should be two characters to the right. A `//` is not a comment in Nix.
- `modules` items should all be on the same vertical level. A space is a separator for list items in Nix.

Preview:

[image: mbp2019prl = nixpkgs.lib.nixosSystem { system = "x86_64-linux"; specialArgs = inputs // { users.root = import ./users/root.nix; }; modules = [ ./device/parallels_desktop ./host/mbp2019prl ./users ]; };]

```lua
vim.opt.wrap = false
vim.opt.expandtab = true
vim.opt.autoindent = false
vim.opt.smartindent = false
vim.opt.cindent = false
vim.opt.shiftwidth = 2
vim.opt.tabstop = 2
```

---

`:verbose setlocal filetype? syntax? autoindent? smartindent? cindent? indentexpr? comments? formatoptions?` returns:

```
  filetype=nix
        Last set from Lua
  syntax=nix
        Last set from /usr/local/Cellar/neovim/0.9.1/share/nvim/runtime/syntax/syntax.vim line 34
noautoindent
        Last set from Lua
nosmartindent
        Last set from Lua
nocindent
        Last set from Lua
  indentexpr=
  comments=s1:/*,mb:*,ex:*/,://,b:#,:%,:XCOMM,n:>,fb:-
  formatoptions=1tjqc
        Last set from Lua
```

Comment: What does `:verbose setlocal filetype? syntax? autoindent? smartindent? cindent? indentexpr? comments? formatoptions?` say when editing a Nix file?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I updated my question. I guess I need to remove `//` from comments to solve the first problem, at least.

Comment: Yeah; I would use `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/nix.vim` and do `:setlocal comments=<whatever>` (For NeoVim the `~/.vim` is probably different). You could also take it up with whoever maintains the runtime files for Nix that you are using.

Comment: I tried `vim.opt.comments:remove("://")`, the entry is removed from `comments`, but the issue persists. I also removed all `formatoptions`. I do edit things in `$HOME/.config/nvim/ftplugin/nix.lua`. Other configurations get applied, so it really should work, hm.

Comment: What *exactly* are you doing when the incorrect indentation occurs? Pressing `=`?

Comment: @Rich mqgg=G`qzz

Answer (score 2):

I believe you have the odd behavior because for `nix` file no specific indentation rules are defined and you end up with the `c` indentation that is odd for `nix`.

To get a basic indentation based on the `{` and `[` you could put the following content in the `~/.config/nvim/indent/nix.vim` for Neovim (or `~/vimfiles/indent/nix.vim` for Vim):

```
" 0. Initialization
" =================

" Only load this indent file when no other was loaded.
if exists("b:did_indent")
  finish
endif
let b:did_indent = 1

setlocal nosmartindent

" Setup indentation expression:
setlocal indentexpr=GetNixIndent()
" Define keys that trigger indentation:
setlocal indentkeys=0{,0},0[,0],!^F,o,O,e

" Only define the function once.
if exists("*GetNixIndent")
  finish
endif

let s:cpo_save = &cpo
set cpo&vim

" 1. Variables
" ============

" 2. Auxiliary Functions
" ======================

" Check if the character at lnum:col is inside a string.
" This function seems not to be reliable
function s:IsInString(lnum, col)
  let nixTypeId = synID(a:lnum, a:col, 1)
  if !nixTypeId
      return 0
  endif
  let nixTypeName = synIDattr(nixTypeId, 'name')
  " let answer = synIDattr(synID(a:lnum, a:col, 1), 'name') == 'nixSimpleString'
  " let answer = index(['nixString', 'nixSimpleString'], synIDattr(synID(a:lnum, a:col, 1), 'name')) >= 0
  let answer = index(['nixSimpleString'], synIDattr(synID(a:lnum, a:col, 1), 'name')) >= 0
  return answer
endfunction

" Check if line 'lnum' has more opening brackets than closing ones.
function s:LineHasOpeningBrackets(lnum)
  " Return a string composed of '0' and '1' indicating for each type of brace
  " ('{', '['') if there are more opening brace than closing brace
  let open_0 = 0 " Number of open '{': '{' lead to 1, '}' lead to '-1'
  let open_2 = 0 " Number of open '[': '[' lead to 1, ']' lead to '-1'
  let line = getline(a:lnum)
  " Get the non string line part:
  let line = substitute(line, '"[^\\"]*\%(\\.[^\\"]*\)*"', '', 'g')
  " Get the non comment part:
  let line = substitute(line, '#.*$', '', '')
  let pos = match(line, '[][{}]', 0)
  while pos != -1
    let idx = stridx('[]{}', line[pos])
    if idx % 2 == 0
      " Open brace:
      let open_{idx} = open_{idx} + 1
    else
      " Close brace:
      let open_{idx - 1} = open_{idx - 1} - 1
    endif
    let pos = match(line, '[][{}]', pos + 1)
  endwhile
  " return (open_0 > 0) . (open_2 > 0) . (open_4 > 0)
  return (open_0 > 0) || (open_2 > 0)
endfunction

" 3. GetNixIndent Function
" =========================

function GetNixIndent()
  " 3.1. Setup
  " ----------

  " Set up variables for restoring position in file.  Could use v:lnum here.
  let vcol = col('.')

  " 3.2. Work on the current line
  " -----------------------------

  " Get the current line.
  let line = getline(v:lnum)
  let ind = -1

  " If we got a closing bracket on an empty line, find its match and indent
  " according to it.
  let col = matchend(line, '^\s*[]}]')

  if col > 0 && !s:IsInString(v:lnum, col)
    call cursor(v:lnum, col)
    let bs = strpart('{}[]', stridx('}]', line[col - 1]) * 2, 2)

    let pairstart = escape(bs[0], '[')
    let pairend = escape(bs[1], ']')
    " let pairline = searchpair(pairstart, '', pairend, 'bW', "synIDattr(synID(line('.'), col('.'), 0), 'name') =~? '\\(nixString\\|nixSimpleString\\|nixComment\\)'")
    let pairline = searchpair(pairstart, '', pairend, 'bW', "synIDattr(synID(line('.'), col('.'), 0), 'name') =~? '\\(nixSimpleString\\|nixComment\\)'")

    if pairline > 0
      let ind = indent(pairline)
    else
      let ind = virtcol('.') - 1
    endif

    return ind
  endif

  " 3.3. Work on the previous line.
  " -------------------------------

  let lnum = prevnonblank(v:lnum - 1)

  if lnum == 0
    return 0
  endif

  " Set up variables for current line.
  let line = getline(lnum)
  let ind = indent(lnum)

  " If the previous line contained an opening bracket add indent
  if line =~ '[[{]'
    let line_has_opening_brackets = s:LineHasOpeningBrackets(lnum)
    if line_has_opening_brackets > 0
      return ind + shiftwidth()
    else
      " return ind
      call cursor(v:lnum, vcol)
    end
  endif

  return ind
endfunction

let &cpo = s:cpo_save
unlet s:cpo_save
```

Comment: I've put this into `$HOME/.config/nvim/ftplugin/nix.vim` and it has helped a lot. It's certainly not perfect, but it's such a relief. I think to make this perfect, it would also indent multiline text between `'' ... ''`. I wonder if it would be possible to have this in Lua as well, but that's purely optional.

Comment: @MartinBraun, thanks for the feedback. In order to improve it it would be good if you could add the multiple line string `''..''` and the way you expect it to be indented. I'm sure it is possible but it certainly more complex ;-)

Comment: @MartinBraun just a nit but it really belongs in `indent/nix.vim` as Vivian pointed out

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I tried to put it to `$HOME/.config/nvim/indent/` initially, but it didn't work.

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt Please see an example at https://github.com/collinarnett/brew/blob/acccf06a880486f06dde2c03391c80875c3c9328/modules/home-manager/neovim/neovim.nix. Single quotes are also valid for multiline text as shown at https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/language/string-interpolation.html#examples. But on the first example you can see that it's often also used to embed code of a different language, that surely makes it no more easy. At least it should indent 2 more spaces than it's ancestor, but it should never forcefully shrink, so manual indention can be applied, for scripts etc.

Comment: @MartinBraun, my understanding is that if we don't want to change the semantic of the file we should not indent the content of the string. We can only indent the first `''` otherwise we change the content of the `nix` file. Do I have the correct understanding?

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt Yes, but you can actually indent strings, because Nix will strip the minimum number of spaces to the left from each line. The first example at https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/language/values.html#type-string illustrates this behavior. So, you can actually indent, you must not ignore additional spaces over the minimal used indention from all lines. It's probably too complicated to implement in a reasonable time, so ignoring string contents should be fine. The current behavior will strip any indents in the string, which is not right.

Comment: @MartinBraun, I have posted a new version. Tell me if it solves your problem :-)

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt Unfortunately, it does not, it still formats strings back to the parent level. https://i.imgur.com/jDzZOlL.gifv

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It would help me if you could give us the input and the desired output. Maybe more than one example would help to understand the corner cases. ;-)